# Differentiable function under specific topological constraints

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, differential-topology

Can you give an example of a set$\:\:\emptyset\neq \mathcal D\large⊂$$\:\mathbb{\Re}\:$ and a differentiable function $\:f$ : $\mathcal D → \mathbb{\Re}\:\:$ such that $$\mathcal D ⊂ \text{Acc}(\mathcal D),\:\frac{\text d}{\text dx}f(x) = 0\:\:\forall x∈\left(\mathcal D \land f\right)\neq  c \in\:\mathbb{\Re}$$.

This was a bonus question on my exam and I'd appreciate any given tips on how to find such an example.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $Acc(D)$ the accumulation points of $D$?

Comment: Yes $Acc(D)$ is the accumulation points of $D$

Comment: Seems that $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if }x>0 \\ 0 &\text{if }x\le 0\end{cases}$$ with $D = (-\infty,0]$ would do.

Comment: @JohnMa But does $\:Acc(D)=(- \infty , 0)\:$? so that $\:D\not\subset Acc(D)$

Comment: $0$ is an accumulation point of $(-\infty, 0]$. @MathFreak

Comment: How is this a nonconstant function on $D$?

Comment: @user39082 : it's not, ^^ I misread.

Comment: If $D$ is not (somehow) connected, then one can come up with an easy conunterexample: Let $D = [0,1] \cup [1,2]$ and $f:D\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) =0$ on $[0,1]$ and $1$ on $[1,2]$.

Comment: Try with $\frac{x^3}{3}-x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my first example was massive overkill.  Take $D = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{x > 0} \\
-1 & \text{x < 0} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you explain in your own words what would it be,because we never saw such theory in a first course in real analysis

Comment: Wouldn't that make the function constant?

Comment: Nope.  It takes on two different values.

Comment: Hum but in French constant would mean a real number that's probably what confused me

Comment: Then, considering my assumption, how would you find a non-real function that matches the criteria in the question? Because although I appriciate the time you've put on the answer, I really thought that a function similar to yours wasn't nearly allowed to answer correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-real function" here?

Comment: Uppon further review of my word to word translation to this question, I must concur with your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Did the question mean something else in French?

Comment: It's just that the way sentences are formulated, it might be possible that an ambiguous statement comes up so that, as far as this example goes, you have to decide whether the function is non-monotonic over some set OR that the function cannot be a real number such as 1. Because in french the word "constant" could mean a real number or it could mean that it is monotonic.